# Angular Query-builder: How to lazily load data for options (possible values) for material auto-complete

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete, angular2-query-builder

I am currently working with [Angular-QueryBuilder](https://github.com/zebzhao/Angular-QueryBuilder) and updating templates for with `ng-container` with [angular-material](/questions/tagged/angular-material).

```
  <!-- Override input component for 'category' type -->
  <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; let field=field; let options=options; type: 'category'">
    <mat-form-field class="categoryValue" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="rule.value" [placeholder]="field.name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">
          {{ opt.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
```

My requirement is to load the data for `options` dynamically. i.e. loading data for this fields from the server after user starts typing (I will be using `mat-auto-complete` instead of `mat-select`).
I am facing some challenges while creating stackblitz for the example. (so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-lpmxwi)

[image]

If anyone has implemented something like that or give some direction, it would be really great.

## Update:

Would like to highligh that using material auto-complete is not an issue. Integrating auto-complete and updating values for it dynamically for query-builder component is the issue. Query-builder is not populating the values if I update it programatically after its initialization like below.

```
  onFieldChange ($event, rule) { // gets called when I change the field dropdown
    if (this.params.config.fields[$event].type === 'category') {
        // updating 'options' (like male and female) dynamically
        // in actual scenario, I will be calling server to get its' values
        this.params.config.fields[$event].options = [
          { name: 'Aaa', value: 'a' },
          { name: 'Bbbb', value: 'b' },
          { name: 'Cccc', value: 'c' },
          { name: 'Dddd', value: 'd' }
        ];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating a FormControl for your input where you will be typing

```
myControl = new FormControl();
```

And then associate it to your input within HTML

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Search"
       aria-label="Search"
       matInput
       [formControl]="myControl"
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

And finally, within your component listen for the value changes and request new data which then you will set as your options

```
this.myControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    filter(searchPhrase => !!searchPhrase),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) // optional but recommended 
  )
  .subscribe(searchPhrase => this.service.searchMyOptions(searchPhrase));
```

Comment: Using auto-complete is not an issue. Integrating auto-complete and updating values for it dynamically for query-builder component is issue.